# Buttons switch-case statement inside Protected Void

Tags: java, android, switch-statement

I am fetching data from `API` in my Android app and transferring it in a `bundle` between activities.

In `OnPostExectute` I created a bundle of JSON *data* and *title* that are displayed in my second activity.

Now I would like to use `switch-case` statement so that when a `button` is clicked, I fetch *data* from correct API and transfer correct title in a `bundle`.

I have assigned `OnClick` function in `xml` file to my buttons.

Could anyone point me in the right direction on how to do that?

Can I put `public void` with `Switch Case` statement inside `Protected Void (OnPostExecute)`? As it doesn't seem to work.

I would be grateful is someone could have a look at my code and give me some tips regarding the structure of it.

Below is my `PostExecute` code:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

    public void btnHelp(View v) {
        Button clickedButton = (Button) v;
        switch (clickedButton.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnHousing:
                String activity_title = getResources().getString(R.string.title2);
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DisplayDataActivity.class);
                Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                extras.putString("title", activity_title);
                extras.putString("JSON_Object", result);
                intent.putExtras(extras);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

            case R.id.btnFood:
                String activity_title = getResources().getString(R.string.title1);
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DisplayDataActivity.class);
                Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                extras.putString("title", activity_title);
                extras.putString("JSON_Object", result);
                intent.putExtras(extras);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

Below are my .java buttons:

```
public void btnHelp1(View view) {
    JSONTask objJSONTask=new JSONTask(MainActivity.this);
    objJSONTask.execute("URL_with_API_1");
}

public void btnHelp2(View view) {

    JSONTask objJSONTask=new JSONTask(MainActivity.this);
    objJSONTask.execute("URL_with_API_2");
}
```

Here is .xml file of my two buttons:

```
<Button
        android:text="@string/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
        android:onClick="btnHelp"
        android:id="@+id/btnHousing"
        />
    <Button
        android:text="@string/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="btnHelp"
        android:id="@+id/btnFood"
        />
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  We are a question-and-answer site, not a coders-for-hire service. Please narrow your question down to a specific problem that would be on-topic for this site.  See: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) and [How to ask a good question when I'm not sure what I'm looking for?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262527/how-to-ask-a-good-question-when-im-not-sure-what-im-looking-for)

Comment: ??? I inserted my code asking what is the potential problem with it and how I should potentially write it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this...

**1. activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<Button
    android:text="@string/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onHouse"
    android:id="@+id/btnHousing"
    />
<Button
    android:text="@string/text2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onFood"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnHousing"
    android:id="@+id/btnFood"
    />
```

**2. OnTaskCompleted.java**

```
public interface OnTaskCompleted {
   public void onTaskOne(String result);
   public void onTaskTwo(String result);
}
```

**3. Constants.java**

```
public class Constants {
  public static final int URL_with_API_1 = 1;
  public static final int URL_with_API_2 = 2;
}
```

**4. JSONTask.java**

```
    public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
       private OnTaskCompleted mOnTaskCompleted;
       private int apiType = 0;

       public JSONTask(int apiType, OnTaskCompleted mOnTaskCompleted) {
         this.apiType = apiType;
         this.mOnTaskCompleted = mOnTaskCompleted;
       }

      @Override
      protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
      }

      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
          String api = params[0];

          // make rest call and return valid data to onPostExecute callback.
          return null;
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
           super.onPostExecute(result);

           //Magic...
           switch (apiType) {
               case Constants.URL_with_API_1:
                    if (mOnTaskCompleted != null) mOnTaskCompleted.onTaskOne(result);
                 break;
               case Constants.URL_with_API_2:
                    if (mOnTaskCompleted != null) mOnTaskCompleted.onTaskTwo(result);
                 break;
              default:
            }
          }
        }
```

**5. MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private String JSON_RESULT_API_1 = "";
private String JSON_RESULT_API_2 = "";
private JSONTask mJsonTask;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //make api 1
    mJsonTask = new JSONTask(Constants.URL_with_API_1, mOnTaskCompleted);
    mJsonTask.execute("URL_with_API_1");

    //make api 2
    mJsonTask = new JSONTask(Constants.URL_with_API_2, mOnTaskCompleted);
    mJsonTask.execute("URL_with_API_2");

}

public void onHouse(View view) {
    String activity_title = getResources().getString(R.string.title2);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DisplayDataActivity.class);
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putString("title", activity_title);
    extras.putString("JSON_Object", JSON_RESULT_API_1);
    intent.putExtras(extras);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void onFood(View view) {
    String activity_title = getResources().getString(R.string.title1);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DisplayDataActivity.class);
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putString("title", activity_title);
    extras.putString("JSON_Object", JSON_RESULT_API_2);
    intent.putExtras(extras);
    startActivity(intent);
}


  OnTaskCompleted mOnTaskCompleted = new OnTaskCompleted() {
    @Override
    public void onTaskOne(String result) {
        JSON_RESULT_API_1 = result;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskTwo(String result) {
        JSON_RESULT_API_2 = result;
    }
    };
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer dear friend! I tried to implement the code, however AndroidStudio underlined "public interface OnTaskCompleted" function giving me the following error: "Inner classes cannot have static declarations". Do you know why it could be? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Hi! It's "public interface OnTaskCompleted" from my JSONTask.java :(

Comment: Absolutely will do! Thank you again! If it's not too much trouble, would you mind they explaining me what sort of logic you used in the code? As I really want to learn Java for android and it looks much different than Python that I know. Sorry that I ask for so much! Thank you again friend!

Comment: I have tried to extend your code to 13 buttons however I don't understand what "private int apiType = 0;" in JSONTask does. Could you please explain to me what number I need to change it to to add another 11 buttons? (I have added other buttons and functions following your method). I would be very grateful. Thank you!!

Comment: Are you make different api request or same api request for 13 button? If yes, How many api's you're calling totally?

Comment: I am calling different APIs. So each button calls individual API. In total there are 15 APIs. Thank you for your help friend!

Comment: Never mind friend!  Then you've to set constants for 15 APIs in Constants class to get different API responses from Async Thread.